# How to use induction on $p+q$ in functional equations

Tags: functions, induction, contest-math, functional-equations

**Question** -

Find all $f : \Bbb Q^+\to\Bbb Q^+$
such that

a) $f(x)+f(1/x)=1$

b) $f(f(x))=f(x+1)/f(x)$.

**My try**  -

By checking some values I get 
$f(1)=1/2$
$f(2)=1/3$
.....

and using induction I proved for all natural numbers...
Now i don't know how to extend it to positive rational
numbers....
For extending something like these we have to first prove non-negativity,additivity,monotonicity , etc ....so that I can prove by standard methods but none of them is working here...

In the hint they wrote prove using induction on p+q 
Where $r=p/q$ is positive rationaI ....
I did not able to see how to do it.....

Any help will be helpful...
Thankyou

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227678) is a similar problem. The functional equation is slightly different, but the solution $f(x)$ is the same, and maybe the induction idea from there will help.

Comment: Do the relations a) and b) hold for the same $f$ ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust Yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim: $ f( \frac{p}{q}) = \frac{q}{p+q}$.
We can check that this satisfies both conditions.

We will prove this by Strong Induction on $ n = p + q$.

Base case: $n = 2$.
This forces $ p = q = 1$, and we need to show that $ f(1) = \frac{1}{2}$.
This follows directly from condition 1, setting $x = 1$.

Induction step: Suppose that for all $ p + q \leq n$, we have $ f( \frac{p}{q}) = \frac{q}{p+q}$.
Now, for a given $ x^* = \frac{ p^* }{ q^*},  p^* + q^* = n+1$.
From condition 1 (and knowing $f(1)$), we may assume that $ p^* > q^*$.
Letting $ x = x^* - 1 = \frac{ p^* - q^* } { q^*}$, and applying condition 2, we get

$$f( \frac{q^*}{p^*} )  = \frac{ f( \frac{p^*}{q^*})  } { f( \frac{ p^* - q^* } { q^* }) }   $$

> Hint: Apply condition 1, and we have a system of linear equations.

Can you take it from here to show that $f( \frac{p^*}{q^*}) = \frac{q^* } { p^* + q^* } $, thereby completing the induction step ?